# Send dropdown form data to php for database query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to construct a query based upon a form consisting of several drop down boxes. I have tried googling around for solutions but haven't been able to get any success and am currently getting 'Databse query failed' and am not sure if this is because my query is constructed wrong or if the form inputs aren't being correctly transferred over to the php file. Any help on this would be amazing as at the moment I am really stuck.

```
    <form action="search.php" method=post>

    <select id="dung-name-select" name="dung-select">
        <option name="" disabled selected hidden>Name</option>
        <option value="*">All</option>
        <option value="Black Rock Hold">Black Rock Hold</option>
        <option value="Court of Stars">Court of Stars</option>
        <option value="Darkheart Thicket">Darkheart Thicket</option>
        <option value="Eye of Azshara">Eye of Azshara</option>
        <option value="Halls of Valor">Halls of Valor</option>
        <option value="Maw of Souls">Maw of Souls</option>
        <option value="Neltharions Lair">Neltharions Lair</option>
        <option value="The Arcway">The Arcway</option>
        <option value="Vault of the Wardens">Vault of the Wardens</option>
    </select>

    <select id="dung-loc-select" name="loc-select">
        <option name="" disabled selected hidden>Location</option>
        <option value="*">All</option>
        <option value="Valsharah">Valsharah</option>
        <option value="Suramar">Suramar</option>
        <option value="Azsuna">Azsuna</option>
        <option value="Stormheim">Stormheim</option>
        <option value="Highmountain">Highmountain</option>
    </select>

    <select id="dung-rating-select" name="rate-select">
        <option name="" disabled selected hidden>Rating</option>
        <option value="*">All</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="Go">

</form>

    <?php

    $dungeon = $_POST["dung-select"];
    $location = $_POST["loc-select"];
    $rate = $_POST["rate-select"];

    //Database Query
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dungeon where Name = $dungeon and Location = $location and Rating = $rate";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed.");
    }
?>
```

NB: the php code is in a separate file to the form.

Comment: what do you get in the `$result` variable when you dump it? it could be on the on your database credentials is causing the error and please observe proper quotation and SQL case. Read about php `concatenation`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate your variables with the string portions of your query to end up with a complete query. So:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dungeon where Name = ".$dungeon." and Location = ".$location." and Rating = ".$rate;
```

I believe you can also use:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM dungeon where Name = {$dungeon} and Location = {$location} and Rating = {$rate}';
```

Either way, unless I'm mistaken, your simply passing your variable names in your query.

Comment: @Kai Jones this should be the right way. Sorry just too lazy to write this code. But the best way supposed to be is to learn it by yourself. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some debug tricks to find the origin of your problem.

First, you may want to check whether or not your data are correctly given to the PHP part. You can add :

```
print_r($_POST);
```

in your PHP file to display the content of the $_POST variable.

Same thing for the SQL query, it may be useful to display it. This would allow you to read it, or to copy it to your SQL manager in order to test it.

This will do the trick :

```
echo $query."<br/>";
```

Let's hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use name attribute in  tag, if you want first option with without value then use 
`<option value="">Name</option>`

Try this:

```
<select id="dung-name-select" name="dung-select">
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Name</option>
        <option value="*">All</option>
        <option value="Black Rock Hold">Black Rock Hold</option>
        <option value="Court of Stars">Court of Stars</option>
        <option value="Darkheart Thicket">Darkheart Thicket</option>
        <option value="Eye of Azshara">Eye of Azshara</option>
        <option value="Halls of Valor">Halls of Valor</option>
        <option value="Maw of Souls">Maw of Souls</option>
        <option value="Neltharions Lair">Neltharions Lair</option>
        <option value="The Arcway">The Arcway</option>
        <option value="Vault of the Wardens">Vault of the Wardens</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those that posted but I have found a solution that seems to be working from my testing what I changed was within the query creation section of the php I added an if elseif statement that will based upon the user inputs change the query construction to filter it.

```
    if ($dungeon == "*" && $location == "*" && $rate == "*") {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dungeon";
} elseif ($dungeon == "*" && $location == "*") {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM dungeon WHERE Rating = '$rate'";
}
```

Using this I can filter when I want a filter to be applied. I also realised that the variables such as $rate need to be surrounded in '' which I was missing before.

Comment: Actually you need to add dots like this in your variable `.$rate.` so it will work properly. :) Please check this [sample](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Answer (score 0):

in addition to TCooper answer, it would be better if you use single quote, double quote:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM dungeon WHERE Name = '".$dungeon."' AND Location = '".$location."' AND Rating = '".$rate."';
```

**EDIT**: And proper SQL casing too!